# Android: Google+ sign in, force to ask credential all the time

Tags: android, google-plus

In my Android application there is possibility for Google+ sign in.
When I press Google+ button, its automatically gets my google account, and sign me in.
But I want to test Google+ with different accounts.

Is there any possibility to force Google+ sdk to ask credentials every time I press Google+ button ?

Did not found anything in documentation.

Comment: have you tried the google settings app where you can disconnect apps from your login?

Comment: oh, nice. How to connect it back later ?

Comment: Just to sign in to my app ? and it will appear in settings again ?

Comment: Actually its did not help me. Still it gets my credentials from somewhere

Comment: Wait, have you setup more accounts on the device? Because it will only accept previously added accounts. On my device I get asked to use one of my two accounts every time I login... You can't add a new account during "runtime".

Comment: I have only my account on the device. But I want to test for example my friend Google+ account. I dont want to add him to my device. Just test app with his account

Comment: Then you need to create at least a second one to be able to switch between accounts.